# What is the netcat or nc command works based on network protocol or port?

Tags: linux, netcat

I just want to know what is the network protocol or port used by `nc` command,anyone answer is much appreciate ^^

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Actually I need to know how it works in principle ,but I think I made a mistaken thought to ask this question.Anyway, thanks for your advice ! I shall be more specifically on my future questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.computerhope.com/unix/nc.htm it looks like TCP or UDP protocol. It works with whichever ports you tell it to look at.

Comment: Thanks James !! That is very helpful ! I think I just made a mistaken thought :p

Comment: @welrod You're welcome. If I answered the question can you please mark the question answered?